# QSqlQueryModel for dynamically changed information

Tags: qt, qml, qsqltablemodel, qsqlquerymodel

Trying to build an application with a UI in QML and accessing data from a Sqlite database.

The QML view has a `TableView` to display information in a data grid with a model in C++.

The model is a class inheriting from `QSqlQueryModel` with a query to the database: `setQuery("SELECT * FROM Samples", GetDataBase())`

I am adding a new row in the database table every second in another thread.

When I navigate to the view where the `TableView` is placed, the grid is populated with the information in the table. All good. But then, every time I add a new row I call `setQuery` again but the table is not updated. If I go back and forth to the view again it is populated with all the new rows.

I thought the view was "automatically" notified whenever the model changed but I suppose I am missing any kind of notification to let the view know that there is new rows or something??

Also...this is just a testing application but I foresee that in my real app the information to be displayed in the grid will change very fast and the table can have several rows of information (order hundred thousand rows) so I wonder if `QSqlQueryModel` is the right model for this kind data.

Comment: Are you using the thread safe version of sqlite?  Did you read the caveats for multithreading of Qt user interfaces?

Comment: You already answered the issue, "_If I go back and forth to the view again it is populated with all the new rows_ ..., you need to update the view when new rows are inserted.

Comment: Also to choose a _high_level_ model considering `QSqlQueryModel` and `QSqlTableModel`, the only difference is if you want an _editable_ model.